# Selenium firefox profile not working anymore

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox

So I was happily using selenium together with Firefox and it seems that my firefox profile wouldn't load anymore some morning. It is driving me nuts to be honest. Whatever I try, the profile that is being used keeps being in the temp folder.

The following snippet is what I am doing

```
def getFireFoxBrowserWithUserFolder(folder) :

options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=" + folder)
firefox = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(folder)
return webdriver.Firefox(options=options, executable_path=r'/home/bunsen/seleniumDriver/geckodriver', firefox_profile=firefox)
```

This worked up until very recent.
I got the newest version of the geckodriver(0.31.0), running it all on Debian stable, so my FF version is 91.10.0ESR (that is also what I see in the selenium browser).

I am at a loss at this point, anyone with the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

first install webdriver_manager:

```
pip install webdriver-manager
```

then:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox

def getFireFoxBrowserWithUserFolder(folder) :
    options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
    options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
    options.add_argument("user-data-dir=" + folder)
    # here you can choose driver version 
    driver =  Firefox(options = options, executable_path=GeckoDriverManager(version="2.26").install())

    return driver
```

More informations about webdriver manager [here](https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/webdriver_manager).